# DNS records set up correctly & server IP loads, but domain still doesn't work

Tags: ssl, dns, vps

I am still relatively new at this, but I recently set up a VPS to work with and also host a website for myself under http://chaoticstupid.media

Yesterday morning I managed to get this domain to function. However, I then realized I wanted to change my DocumentRoot - which I promptly did without issues (as far as I can tell!). However, I then tried to use certbot (as per Hostinger's instructions) to install an SSL certificate, and since I did that - the domain (neither www. or regular) will load anymore.

So step by step:

- Unmanaged VPS hosting at Hostinger with CentOS 7 installed, running apache
- Domain chaoticstupid.media was functional pointing to the SSH IP for my server
- Changed DocumentRoot for VPS server to a different folder
- Used Certbot to install SSL certificates

Now: neither domain name functions, **but** if I visit the server IP directly then it loads the website just fine.

Struggled with DNS records (domain hosted at GoDaddy) but I have those set up correctly now and still no dice.

The only thing I can think of is that in the Hostinger instructions (https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ssl-certificate-on-centos-7#How_to_Install_SSL_Certificate_with_Lets_Encrypt) it says I should have gotten a secondary prompt asking me about whether to redirect HTTPS traffic - I never received this prompt, but I don't know if that might be causing this issue.

Please let me know if you need any additional information; I'm really a little lost as to what the problem is here.

Thank you,

CS

Answer (score 1):

It is not a DNS issue. Your server only listen on port 80 (and not also on port 443). When a webclient hits http://chaoticstupid.media it receives a `301 Moved Permanently` with `Location: https://chaoticstupid.media/`. So HTTP redirects to HTTPS but there is nothing listening on that port (443). Please check your http server config and setup a correct SSL configuration.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Thank you so much - you were absolutely right. I messed up big time in the set up.

Comment: No problem... I'm here to help.